# How to apply the t-test to data with multiple observations per pair

Tags: time-series, t-test, paired-data

Imagine I collect time series data from a group of people before and after treatment. Now if I want to compare the results before and after should I take the average of the time series and apply a paired t-test? I assume taking average will lose some information. Is there any other way to apply a comparison test without losing any time series information?

An exact question/problem has been posted here: [Paired t-test with multiple observations per pair](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538747/paired-t-test-with-multiple-observations-per-pair). Did not understand the accepted answer and could not comment due minimum reputation required.

Comment: The accepted answer proposes a mixed effects regression model which is considerably more involved then any t-test and unfortunately there is no really beginner friendly answer to your question. Search "repeated measurements" and/or "mixed effects" or have someone help you or loose information through averaging.

Comment: If you want something about that answer explained, you should ask more specific questions (or request resources). I don't think you'll get any very simple suggestions that don't involve strong assumptions that may well not be reasonable in practice.